# Using Slack, how do you send direct message to user based on their "Member ID?

Tags: slack, slack-api

How do you send a direct message to a user in Slack, using their unique "Member ID". Slack seems to only accept a Slack handle as an acceptable username.

I'm new to Slack and thanks in advance for the help (please let me know if this needs to be moved, etc.).

Comment: Can you share what you have tried? Do you have program code or are you looking for some else to write the code for you?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you meant **user ID** when you said "member ID", you can use that as channel parameter in [`chat.postMessage`](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage) to send a direct message to that user.

Example for user with User ID `U12345678`:

```
curl -X POST "https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage" -H  "accept: application/json" -d token=TOKEN -d channel=U12345678 - d text=Hello
```

Comment: IS this still valid? I am using python SDK and cannot use bot token to send the IM